# env varibles undefined in express js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I want to use env variable in my project to connect to my database.

Here is my code :

```
const Sequelize = require("sequelize");
require("dotenv").config();

console.log(process.env.MYSQL_PASS);
const sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env.MYSQL_NAME, process.env.MYSQL_USER, process.env.MYSQL_PASS, {
   host: process.env.MYSQL_HOST,
   port: process.env.MYSQL_PORT,
   dialect: "mysql",
});
```

I'm using latest node version.
The output is still `undefined`

Comment: Where you use `.env` file located?

Comment: and what's the output of `console.log(process.env)` ?

Comment: my .env is located in the root of the project . not in any folder or something

Comment: Try to move line with dotenv import upper. dotenv should be imported as early as possible in your code.

Comment: check your .env file permissions

Comment: The `.env` has to be in your CWD. Is it the case?

Answer (score 1):

Can you try giving the path of your .env file in dotenv for example:

```
require("dotenv").config({ path: `./.env` });
```

Or the relative path of the env file.

Comment: Yeah i tried something like that in and it worked